# ASP MVC API Exception Truncate StackTrace

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Right now I have a portion of code that is throwing an internal service error. I noticed my clients are getting a very detailed stack trace. I don't want this, I just want to send the 'message' property.

How can I extend my MVCAPI controller to truncate the exception result to only issue the message and not the exception type and stack trace ?

```
public class TruncateExceptionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Response == null)
            return;

        if (actionContext.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            // Where do I get the exception message so I can set content ?
            // Also will it be serialized properly (MediaTypeFormatter?)
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but `ActionFilterAttribute`s are usually executed before the Action method, correct?

Comment: Do you have <customErrors mode="Off"/> ?

Comment: By default this is off in the release version, are you uploading the debug version to your production website?